# Split View Controller Object Not Showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I started developing an app for the iPhone, but then decided I want to have it to be universal for both iPhone and iPad.

What I did was just go to the project target -> build setting -> targeted device family -> iPhone/iPad

and also in the summary -> devices -> universal.

I'm pretty sure this doesn't finish the conversion because when I go to one of the controller nib files, I can't create a Split view Controller.

What is the proper way to convert the iPhone application to universal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have to change TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY in project settings to run app on bouth devices.

http://i-and-world.appspot.com/2011/01/10/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Comment: I tried another method; basically I duplicated the target and transferred it to iPad? Does this work too?

Comment: please always use procedural one.so that apple gave the option Target for iphone/ipad.since image size and pixel rate is different for both.